# Unhandled Promise rejection: Invalid configuration of route 'PlayerManagement/PlayerMain/:id/': redirectTo and component cannot be used together

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular2-routing, angular5

**update 1:**

after removing the component from the routing now the application is running for other components, fine but if we go back to that player component from another component in the browser i am getting below error

```
VM30741:34 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'PlayerManagement'
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:418)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:403)
    at zone.js:451
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:225)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4943)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:224)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:125)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:357)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:297)


TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at console.window.console.error (<anonymous>:36:101)
    at defaultErrorLogger (core.js:1659)
    at ErrorHandler.handleError (core.js:1720)
    at Object.next (core.js:5700)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:4538)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:239)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:186)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:126)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:90)
```

- I am upgrading from angular 2 to angular 5
- after upgrading I am getting below three errors.
- I used the below link and did update but still following errors are happening.
- I googled for the error but not able to find anything
- any idea how to fix it.
- it would be great if you let me know how to fix it...so that in future I will fix it by myself
- providing code snippet and package.json below

app.routing.ts
https://hastebin.com/ufetoxozon.js

package.json
https://hastebin.com/adatojuput.json

```
<!-- language-all: lang-or-tag-here -->


VM3365:34 Unhandled Promise rejection: Invalid configuration of route 'PlayerManagement/PlayerMain/:id/': redirectTo and component cannot be used together ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Invalid configuration of route 'PlayerManagement/PlayerMain/:id/': redirectTo and component cannot be used together
    at validateNode (router.js:757)
    at validateConfig (router.js:729)
    at validateNode (router.js:779)
    at validateConfig (router.js:729)
    at validateNode (router.js:779)
    at validateConfig (router.js:729)
    at Router.resetConfig (router.js:4958)
    at new Router (router.js:4820)
    at setupRouter (router.js:7305)
    at _callFactory (core.js:11128) Error: Invalid configuration of route 'PlayerManagement/PlayerMain/:id/': redirectTo and component cannot be used together
    at validateNode (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js?:757:15)
    at validateConfig (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js?:729:9)
    at validateNode (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js?:779:9)
    at validateConfig (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js?:729:9)
    at validateNode (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js?:779:9)
    at validateConfig (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js?:729:9)
    at Router.resetConfig (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js?:4958:9)
    at new Router (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js?:4820:14)
    at setupRouter (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/router/esm5/router.js?:7305:35)
    at _callFactory (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js?:11128:28)


Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Invalid configuration of route 'PlayerManagement/PlayerMain/:id/': redirectTo and component cannot be used together
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:418)
    at zone.js:454
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:225)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:125)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:357)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:297)


VM3365:36 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at console.window.console.error (<anonymous>:36:101)
    at consoleError (zone.js:346)
    at _loop_1 (zone.js:371)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:375)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:297)
```

Comment: I thought the error was pretty self-explanatory..

Comment: @ChauTran hi, can you tell me how to fix it....thanks

Comment: Did you try taking out the `component` from your `redirectTo` route?

Comment: @ChauTran hey if I try to remove the routing...I am not able to redirect to that module...any fix is there?